# Screen is getting freezed when clicking on a drop down button using testcafe automation

Tags: automation, testcafe

Targeted element is //input[@id='add-to-wishlist-button']

When i click the element drop down box the screen gets hanged in both chrome and firefox browser.
Chrome Browsers verison is Version 97.0.4692.99
Testcafe version is testcafe@1.18.1

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided is insufficient. Try updating to the latest TestCafe version.  If the problem still persists, i suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and add required information and sample code to reproduce the issue.